# PHP Change image color to transparent then use as a mask

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I'm trying to change the background colour of an image from white, to transparent, then to use that as a mask to put over another image. (Cannot be transparent already, because another part is which is used as a mask over yet another image)... layers are fun :)

Full code:

```
<?
include '../includes/db.php';
include '../includes/checks.php';

$type = $_GET['t']; //shirt | shorts
$style = $_GET['s'];
$z = $_GET['z']; // home | away
$a = $_GET['a'];
$b = $_GET['b'];

$aR = hexdec($a['0'].$a['1']);
$aG = hexdec($a['2'].$a['3']);
$aB = hexdec($a['4'].$a['5']);
$bR = hexdec($b['0'].$b['1']);
$bG = hexdec($b['2'].$b['3']);
$bB = hexdec($b['4'].$b['5']);

// main top
$imgname = '../images/kits/test/'. $uTime .'.png';
$im = imagecreatetruecolor( 100, 100); 
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, $aR, $aG, $aB);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $red);

$mask = imagecreatefrompng('../images/kits/test/6-space.png'); 
imagecopyresampled($im, $mask, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($im), imagesy($im), imagesx($mask), imagesy($mask));
imagedestroy($mask);

$mask = imagecreatefrompng('../images/kits/test/4-shadows.png'); 
imagecopyresampled($im, $mask, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($im), imagesy($im), imagesx($mask), imagesy($mask));
imagedestroy($mask);

$mask = imagecreatefrompng('../images/kits/test/1-tag.png'); 
imagecopyresampled($im, $mask, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($im), imagesy($im), imagesx($mask), imagesy($mask));
imagedestroy($mask);

// design
$im2 = imagecreatetruecolor( 100, 100); 
$red = imagecolorallocate($im2, $bR, $bG, $bB);
imagefill($im2, 0, 0, $red);

$mask = imagecreatefrompng('../images/kits/test/5-logo.png'); 
imagecopyresampled($im2, $mask, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($im2), imagesy($im2), imagesx($mask), imagesy($mask));
imagedestroy($mask);
imagecolortransparent($im2, imagecolorallocatealpha($im2, 0, 0, 0, 127));
imagealphablending($im2, false);
imagesavealpha($im2, true);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im2,255,255,255);
imagecolortransparent($im2, $white);

// merge and result
imagecopyresampled($im, $im2, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($im), imagesy($im), imagesx($im2), imagesy($im2));
imagepng($im, $imgname);
imagedestroy($im2);
imagedestroy($im);
echo '<img src="', $imgname ,'">';
?>
```

Comment: as a side note, when I output the images, it shows the white as 255,255,255 and 254,254,254. Also, if I use imagecolorset, it doesn't seem to do anything :/

Comment: Out of interest why have you tagged this with Imagemagick when it is using GD?

Comment: Incase there is something that can be done in Imagemagick... I'm pretty new to manipulating images, so anything suggested may help... seems like nobody knows an answer then, too hard maybe? :P

Answer (score 1):

A couple of methods with Imagemagick ( the second example came from http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/ )

Change all white in the image to transparent

```
convert input.jpg -matte -fuzz 1% -transparent rgb(255,255,255) mask.png
```

Change all the white in an image that is connected to the pixel in the top left corner.

```
convert input.jpg -alpha set -channel RGBA -fuzz 1% -fill none -floodfill +0+0 white mask.png
```

In php use like this:

```
exec("convert input.jpg -matte -fuzz 1% -transparent rgb\(255,255,255\) mask.png");
```

The command above is changing white rgb(255,255,255) actualy +- 1% of the rgb value to transparent

Comment: Okay lets try without Imagemagick, sorry! No idea how to use it

Comment: I think Imagemagick is a lot simpler to use that GD; you can check out my website for examples with php.